# DataInputStream and readLine() with UTF8

Tags: java, utf-8

I've got some trouble with sending a UTF8 string from a c socket to a java socket. 
The following method works fine:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
main.title = in.readLine();
```

but then I need a `int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[] b, int offset, int length)` method which does not exist for a BufferedReader. So then I tried to take a DataInputStream

```
DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

but everything it reads is just rubbish.

Then I tried to use the `readLine()` method from `DataInputStream` but this doesn't give me the correct UTF8 string.

You see my dilemma. Can't I use two readers for one InputStream? Or can I convert the `DataInputStream.readLine()` result and convert it to UTF8?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you are sending both text and binary data on the same socket, in the same "conversation"? There should be no problem creating two readers for the same inputstream. The problem is knowing when (and how much) to read which reader. They will both consume (and advance) the underlying stream when you read from them, since you have mixed types of data. You could just read the stream as bytes and then convert the bytes explicitly in your code (new String(bytes, "UTF-8") etc). Or you could split your communication onto two different sockets.

Comment: @pap: that's well worth of an answer ;-)

Comment: @pap: I agree, post the comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know from the [design of the UTF-8 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3) that the only usage of the value `0x0A` is the LINE FEED (`'\n'`). Therefore, you can read until you hit it:

```
  /** Reads UTF-8 character data; lines are terminated with '\n' */
  public static String readLine(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (true) {
      int b = in.read();
      if (b < 0) {
        throw new IOException("Data truncated");
      }
      if (b == 0x0A) {
        break;
      }
      buffer.write(b);
    }
    return new String(buffer.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
  }
```

*I am making the assumption that your protocol uses `\n` as a line terminator. If it doesn't - well, it is generally useful to point out the constraints you're writing to.*

Comment: Ah great job! That's what I needed! Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 3):

Do **NOT** use BufferedReader and DataInputStream on the same InputStream!! I did that and spent days trying to figure out why my code broke. BufferedReader can read more than what you extract from it into its buffer, resulting in situation when the data I was supposed to read with the DataInputStream being "in the BufferedReader". This resulted in lost data which caused my program to "hang" waiting for it to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should not mismatch the `BufferedReader` and `DataInputStream` here. `DataInputStream` has `readLine()` too, so use it. 
And yet another comment. I am not sure it is a problem but avoid multiple calls of `socket.getInputStream()`. Do it once and then wrap it as you want using other streams and readers.

Comment: I tried to use the readLine() method from DataInputStream but then I don't get the correct unicode signs. The documentation says that this method is deprecated: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29. So now I've take two readers with 

inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF8"));

Comment: First, the bufferedReader reads some text. Then the dataInputStream has to read some bytes but it gets stuck und the read() method returns -1 although I've sent more bytes than the dataInputStream has received. Does the bufferedReader consume some bytes? oO

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding it correctly that you are sending both text and binary data on the same socket, in the same "conversation"? There should be no problem creating two readers for the same inputstream. The problem is knowing when (and how much) to read which reader. They will both consume (and advance) the underlying stream when you read from them, since you have mixed types of data. You could just read the stream as bytes and then convert the bytes explicitly in your code (new String(bytes, "UTF-8") etc). Or you could split your communication onto two different sockets.